# Correct way to use onTokenRefresh() of Firebase Messaging and Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a Flutter application and want to send Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications specifically to different users with their respective Firebase Token. The problem is when the app is reinstall or after some period of time, the Firebase Token is regenerated.

How can I use the **onTokenRefresh()** method to notice the change of token continuously (even when the app is not opened) and send the new token to my backend server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((String token) {
    print("New token: $token");

  // sync token to server
  });

  String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  // sync token to server
  print("Token: $token");
  //runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this code. You will always be writing data on the server with the new FCM token every time the app opens even if the token hadn't changed.

Comment: That is just a basic example. You could persist the last token used in local storage and check if it's the same and avoid saving it to the database. Checking in the database would cost more because a read costs the same as a write.

Comment: Read does **NOT** cost the same as write. It costs 1/3 of the write.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it costs less. But it would cost you more than saving it in local storage.